# Javascript event issue

Tags: javascript, events, publish-subscribe

I am creating a link that changes text when it is clicked.  I want the link text to change back to the original text after all the processing is complete.  It was working fine, but the code was spread all over my js file, so I am trying to abstract it into a function.  This is the function, `textToggle`.  In the textToggle function we are publishing an event.  This event is the one that I cannot get to fire off at the right time.

```
var textToggle = function(data) {
  var original_text = $(data.element).text();
  var id = data.id;
  var $element = $(data.element);
  $element.text(data.replacement_text);
  $('body').on(data.event, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.text(original_text);
  });
};
```

Here is the function that sets up the textToggle.  At the end of the function, we are triggering another event `clinical.status'.

```
$('#clinicalPatients').on('click', '[data-role="auth-process"]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);
  var _id = $target.attr('id');

  textToggle({
    id: _id,
    element: $this,
    replacement_text: "Processing...",
    event: "clinical.status.finished"
  });

  $('#clinicalPatients').trigger('clinical.status', [{
    id: _id,
    target: $target,
    action: _type
  }]);
});
```

At the end of `clinical.status` is when I want to fire the event in toggleText, `clinical.status.finished`.  This is the code for that event.

```
$('body').trigger('clinical.status.finished', [{
  id: originalId
}]);
```

`clinical.status.finished` is not getting triggered at the right time.  There is no other place in the code that is using this, so it has to be the way that I am setting it up.  If I leaved that event out of the `toggleText` function, and drop it in the function where I set up the `toggleText` function, then everything works like it is supposed to.  By putting `on` event into a separate function, will this cause issues.  Please, any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `not getting triggered at the right time`?

Comment: Sorry to waste everyone's time, but my finished task was happening so quickly that it appeared nothing was happening.  Thanks again.